# SQL query to combine existence check and condition check

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, call A and B. A has a foreign key on B. call them A_ID and B_ID respectively. But the constraint not enforced in the design. I am not supposed to change the schema. I need to delete entries from table A based on 2 conditions. 
1)If table B doesn't contain A_ID
2)If some condition on B is met.

I have formed a query something like this. But I dont think its optimal. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
delete from A where A_ID not in (select B_ID from B where status='x' ) 
                 or A_ID not in (select B_ID from B)
```

Comment: In your example "A_ID not in (select B_ID from B where status='x' )" is a subset of  A_ID not in (select B_ID from B) is that what you intended?

Comment: JustABitOfCode is right! (select B_ID from B where status = 'x' is a SUBSET of select B_ID from B, this means that the condition (select B_ID from B where status = 'x') is redundant.

Comment: i dont think its a subset. though it looks like so. as i said i need to delete 1)if b doesn't contain that id and 2) if it contains and a condition holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `not exists` to delete rows without a matching entry in table B.  This one treats `status = 'x'` as if no match was found, i.e. it will delete those rows:

```
delete  A
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    B
        where   B.B_ID = A.A_ID
                and status <> 'x'
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

JustABitOfCode  and UltraCommit told about omitting one part
furthermore, if it's a foreign key, you can say to keep deleting unwanted A in definition:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  uniqeidentifire A_ID
  , FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES B(B_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This will Automatically delete each A that does not have a B match

and this is more efficient

Comment: Smart suggestion, compliments!

Comment: yah you are right. but as i mentioned, i cant change the schema now.

Answer (score 0):

As just explained from JustABitOfCode, please remove the condition:

```
(select B_ID from B where status='x')
```

because it is redundant: the result set of the previous select, is a SUBSET of the result set of the following select:

```
(select B_ID from B)
```